# How to multiple different types of values from a method in java and use it in the main class?

Tags: java

I have made a method which I will use several times in my main, but change the paremeters each time. I cannot figure out how to call each different values from that method. below is what I have so far for my method, it contains type Strings, int and JLABEL.

```
private static void method(String a, int b, int c, int d, String e, JLabel f) {
    try {
        a = (String) field1.getText();
        b = (int) (Double.parseDouble(studentid.getText());
        c = (studentname.getText()));
        d = (Integer.parseInt(hourtravel.getText()));
        countCommandsAdded.setText("e");
        contentPane.remove(f);
    }catch (NumberFormatException arg0){

    }   

}
```

How can I return, in this case I need to return String a, int b, int c, int d, and remove JLabel f from my design and change text of String e.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a class which can carry all those types. Return an instance of those class initialized to carry those values.

Comment: Don't use empty catch blocks.

Comment: Not sure if I got the quesiotn right, but maybe you're looking for generics?

Comment: Basically, I was going to paste this code if not created in method in for 8/10 different buttons. This is going to make my code not efficient. So what I want to do is make a method and call that method in those 8/10 buttons and set the parameters so that it stores the relevant information that I can use in my class.

Answer (score 0):

You can have methods with the same name in the same class, with different parameters, and different return types. This is called **Overloading** and it is better explained here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html.

In your case, though it is not the most brilliant solution, you can have multiple `method(...)` with the parameters you want, performing different logic.

As other poster suggest, a better, more OOP compliant solution would be to use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), or to use a class as wrapper for your different values.